# Maximum of Lipschitz function is Lipschitz (Proof Check)

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following statement:

Let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbf{R}^d$, suppose $f_1, f_2: \mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ are Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively, then the function $f_{max}(x) = \max \{f_1(x), f_2(x)\}$ is also Lipschitz.

Proof:
Let $L=\max\{L_1, L_2\}$.
From Lipschitz continuity of $f_1$ and $f_2$, fix $x, x' \in \mathcal{X}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
f_1(x) \leq f_1(x') + L_1 \cdot \|x-x'\| \leq f_{max}(x') + L \cdot \|x-x'\|
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
f_2(x) \leq f_2(x') + L_2 \cdot \|x-x'\| \leq f_{max}(x') + L \cdot \|x-x'\|.
\end{equation*}
Consequently, we have
\begin{equation*}
f_{max}(x) \leq f_{max}(x') + L \cdot \|x-x'\| 
\end{equation*}
In a similar way, we can show that
\begin{equation*}
f_{max}(x') \leq f_{max}(x) + L \cdot \|x-x'\| 
\end{equation*}
Therefore, for all $x$, $x' \in \mathcal{X}$,
\begin{equation*}
|f_{max}(x') - f_{max}(x)| \leq L \cdot \|x - x'\|.
\end{equation*}
By definition, the function $f_{max}: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is Lipschitz.

Could someone check if I prove this statement correctly? Thank you!

Comment: *As written,* no. But I assume that is just the result of typos. If the first inequality were just $f_1$ and $L_1$ except the far rhs, and similarly the second was all $f_2$ and $L_2$, then it would be correct.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for spotting my typo. I have fixed that now, does the proof make sense now?

Comment: Yes - that was the only issue I saw.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you. Appreciate it.